# Using different virtual desktops in different monitors

Tags: 18.04, kde, kde5, virtualdesktop

I want to use different virtual desktops for different monitors (i.e laptop and external LCD) in KDE plasma 5.18 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It's a feature that has been requested since quite some time, but no, it is not possible.

See also [this feature request](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107302).